# Complex eigenvalues and rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ real matrix with two complex eigenvalues $z_1,z_2$ such that $z_1z_2 = 1$. 
Prove that $A$ is a rotation by some angle $\theta$.

There are multiple ways to prove this. However, I am looking for the most "elementary" proof possible. Usually one can regard $A$ as a matrix with complex coefficients and find an eigenbasis consisting of complex vectors to conclude that $A^{-1} = A^t$, and the proof follows from there.

Suppose you are trying to justify this to someone who never seen complex vector spaces before, how do you derive it?

Comment: some word-smithing is needed to explain what "two complex eigenvalues" means, otherwise you have counterexamples like $\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1  \\0  & 1\end{matrix}\right]$  which isn't a rotation matrix. Presumably "complex" means  "non-real"

Comment: Although this is false, as the answers so far demonstrate, $A$ is similar to a rotation.

Comment: @amd Yes, I took this "fact" for granted. When I re-did the a non-elementary approach to this problem I noticed that if $A$ has two complex eigenvectors $u$ and $v$ so that it their real parts span $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $A$ is similar to a rotation matrix. Is there a simple extra condition that allows one to conclude that $A$ is a rotation matrix?

Comment: How simple a condition are you looking for, aside from checking directly that it’s of the form $\small{\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}}$? E.g., $AA^*=A^*A$ would be sufficient here. That makes $A$ a normal matrix with eigenvalues on the unit circle, hence unitary. Skew-symmetry might even be enough, although I haven’t verified that.

Comment: @amd I should have clarified in my question that I am looking for a simple condition on the eigenvalues themselves, not on the matrix.

Comment: There isn’t any such condition on the eigenvalues, of course: any matrix similar to a rotation will have the same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

That is false.

Since the eigenvalues of our matrix $A$ are conjugate, both have modulus $1$ and they are in the form $\cos(\theta)\pm i\sin(\theta)$. Then $tr(A)=2\cos(\theta), \det(A)=1$.

Finally, $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&2\cos(\theta)-a\end{pmatrix}$, where $2a\cos(\theta)-a^2-bc=1$, depends on $2$ parameters (in addition to $\theta$) and, then, is not necessarily a rotation.

EDIT. You want an additional condition so that $A$ is orthogonal. This one must concern its eigenvectors; indeed, a rotation admits always $[1,\pm i]^T$ as a basis of eigenvectors; that is, it suffices to say that $A$ commutes with ONE rotation.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ Let $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. If $\det(A)=1$ and $A$ commutes with $Rot(\pi/2)$, then $A\in O^+(2)$ -and conversely-.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Consider e.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ 1&-1}.
$$
Its two eigenvalues are $\pm i$ but $A$ is clearly not a rotation matrix.

Comment: What extra condition is missing to conclude that $A$ is a rotation?

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki That $A$ is normal (i.e. $AA^T=A^TA$) is enough.

Comment: Sorry, using my smartphone, by mistake I downvoted your post. Write an edit,  and I will upvote it.